# How do I use data stored in a Blob as a view?

Tags: view, blob, playframework

We're currently doing a project that accepts user-provided html and has our own injected into it.  This perfectly matches Play's abilities.  However, I am at a loss as to how to use dynamic content as a view template without manual intervention.  It seemed best to use a blob to store the information (given that there could be thousands of templates) and somehow load that way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just thought to clarify something.  I don't want to just dump the user file in the view directory.  It would need to be scrubbed first.  I can handle parsing that out just fine.  I was just hoping to make this easier than I was thinking about handling this originally.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this (I’m not convinced this is a good idea), have a look at the implementation of `play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(String, Map<String,Object>)` in the Play source, to see code that loads a template, binds variables and renders the template.